# Fourier series and floor function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

It is easy to see that the the floor function on $[0,1]$ has Fourier expansion:
$$[x] = x - {1 \over 2} + {1 \over \pi }\sum\limits_{n > 0} {{{\sin (2\pi x)} \over n}}.$$

Let $a$ be a positive integer. My question is: what about the function $[ax]$, can I replace $x$ by $ax$ in the Fourier series? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be $[x]=0$? How is there an $x$ term in a Fourier series? And shouldn't it be $2\pi n x$?

Comment: yes, $$x = {1 \over 2} - {1 \over \pi }\sum\limits_{n > 0} {{{\sin (2\pi x)} \over n}} $$.

Comment: For $x\in[0,1/a]$, you can replace $x$ with $ax$ in the Fourier series.

Comment: So, what are you doing with the floor function? The floor function is essentially zero in $[0,1]$, and thus it has Fourier series $0$. What you have written is not a Fourier series for $[x]$ since Fourier series do not have an $x$ term. So what are you trying to say?

Comment: If you want to find the Fourier coefficients of $[ax]$ on $[0,1]$, then just ask that.

Comment: @MokhtariYacine Point about the missing $n$ was that as written $\sum\limits_{n > 0} \cfrac{\sin (2\pi x)}{n} = \sin (2\pi x) \cdot\sum\limits_{n > 0} \cfrac{1}{n}\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Fourier expansions depend on the period of the function (or the period we impose on the function, if it's defined only on an interval).

First of all, the equation
$$
[x] = x - {1 \over 2} + {1 \over \pi }\sum\limits_{n > 0} {{{\sin (2\pi nx)} \over n}}
$$
is true for all real numbers $x$ (except integers, where the left- and right-hand sides account differently for the jump discontinuity). However, this is not technically a Fourier expansion of $[x]$ on $[0,1]$; as commenters have pointed out, that function is $0$ almost everywhere and thus has the trivial Fourier expansion.

What is really intended here is that the function $x-[x]$ is periodic with period $1$, and therefore has a well-defined period-$1$ Fourier expansion, which is indeed ${1 \over 2} - {1 \over \pi }\sum_{n > 0} {{{\sin (2\pi nx)} \over n}}$.

Now, it is a true statement that
$$
[ax] = ax - {1 \over 2} + {1 \over \pi }\sum\limits_{n > 0} {{{\sin (2\pi nax)} \over n}}
$$
(just substitute $ax$ for $x$). This is the correct period-$\frac1a$ Fourier expansion of the periodic function $ax-[ax]$.

However, if for some reason you wanted to define a function $f(x)$ to equal $ax-[ax]$ for $0\le x<1$, and then extend the function $f(x)$ to be periodic with period $1$, then its Fourier expansion would be (for generic values of $a$) very different than the formula above.

Comment: Good point, fixed (you could also edit / suggest an edit directly)